# can someone explain to me why I get this error 'int' object is not callable in my class

Tags: python

so here is my code

```
class Account:

    def __init__(self,owner,balance):

        self.owner = owner

        self.balance = balance

    def __str__(self):

        return (f" Account Owner : {self.owner} \t\n Account balance : ${self.balance}")

    def deposit(self,deposit):

        self.deposit = deposit

        self.balance = self.balance+self.deposit

        print(f"Deposit Accepted : {self.deposit}")

acc1 = Account("John",6000)
```

The problem is when I call the deposit method twice I got this error
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
The first call I don't get any error but the second time I got that previous error

Comment: Question to you: if you have an Account instance `acc`, is `acc.deposit` a method or a number?

Comment: acc.deposit is number and acc.deposit(amount) is method

Comment: I get where I get the error the first try acc1.deposit(500) will work
and acc1.deposit =500
but the second try 
acc1.deposit(600) it's like I'm doing  500(600)
it that right

Comment: You effectively are. Please see my solution below.

Answer (score 2):

**The issue**: On the first call of the `deposit` method you are creating an instance variable  `self.deposit` which has the same name as the method.  The next time you invoke `deposit` it is actually trying to call the instance variable hence the `int is not callable` error.

**Solution**: You can correct the error by modifying your `deposit` method so that it does not create the instance variable since it is not used outside the scope of the function.

Here is the modified function:

```
def deposit(self, deposit):
    self.balance = self.balance + deposit
    print(f"Deposit Accepted : {deposit}")
```

If you do need to create an instance variable to store the deposit then simply use a different (unique) name.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the method deposit.  But that is also the name of the variable you pass in.   When you run `self.deposit = deposit`, you are really replacing that method with an integer.  Solution is to use distinct names.